# Zombie.js firing a visit callback before GET request completes

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm running into an issue where using zombie.js to access a localhost url seems to fire the `visit` callback before the "response" event returns. At least, it before the `"Zombie: GET http://localhost/ => 200"` message is logged in debug mode.

```
var Browser = require('zombie');

Browser.visit('http://localhost/', 
  { 
    debug: true
  }, 
  function (err, browser) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(browser.success, err);
  }
);
```

When I run this, I get the following:

```
Zombie: Opened window http://localhost/ 
Zombie: Event loop is empty
false undefined
Zombie: GET http:/localhost/ => 200
```

When I run it on my live site, I get the following:

```
Zombie: Opened window http://mylivesite.com/ 
Zombie: GET http:/mylivesite.com/ => 200
Zombie: Loaded document http://mylivesite.com/
Zombie: Event loop is empty
true undefined
```

Any reason why `console.log(browser.success, err)` runs before the GET request when I'm running it on localhost? Even with `maxWait` set to 10s, still no luck.